# A new method to avoid Robots

Tags: php, bots, captcha

I've a form with a text input for email. I don't want to use the captcha to avoid robots. But I used to use a method.

I give my email text input a name="courrier" or another name and I create another hidden text input with name="email".

In the php code, I've put a condition:

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
  // add infos in the database
} else {
  //this is not allowed to use robots
}
```

Is this method useful to avoid some captcha that can be annoying in the website?

Comment: This is called a honeypot.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29

Comment: @Gazler I don't think a single hidden HTML input element can be considered a honeypot...

Comment: @meager You are setting a trap for bots.  I'd say that is a honeypot.  Altough I'd hide the field with css and make it a normal input.  http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/11/honeypot-captcha.aspx is an article on the technique.

Comment: @meager the trap usually works.. except when the bots are some kind of intelligent.

Comment: Well, now that makes sense - selecting a solution which of which you know it does **NOT** solve the problem and then ask wether it is useful... Live with a captcha or live with spam. Your call.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thank you ... back in 2010, it was my first year as a web developer, I didn't know much back then... :)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg , Actually, when I see this question now .. it sounds very naive.

Comment: @SmootQ Jeez, how did I stumble on this one? And how did I not realize that this was grave digging...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, it happens, you search and you find. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this method useful to avoid some captcha that can be ennoying in the website???

To a certain extent, yes. It's not foolproof, but it'll certainly block some attempts.

Comment: thank you... but I really want to know even if someone won't develop an intelligent robot in the future